# Asking a Professor for a review of a university application research supplement

Tags: application

As part of the application to a particular university, I can submit a research supplement which is a paper I have written which will be reviewed by the university's faculty. However, it must be accompanied by a letter from a 'research supervisor' regarding the work.

The paper I have written is based on a paper written by a professor from another university, and as I am currently in high school and none of the staff here can review it, I thought it would be great if I could get said professor to write such a letter.

Firstly, would it be appropriate to send such a request, and is it likely to be fulfilled?

Note: For the purposes of your answers, you may assume the paper is in fact correct, and a serious piece of research, which although it presents original results, is 'orthodox.' I am aware professors sometimes get sent crazy letters from people with wacky theories (I've even seen some crop up on the physics SE).

Comment: I don't see any reason it would be inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely not inappropriate. But professors are busy people, and you are likely to be put in the "crank" bin without a detailed reading. Be careful crafting your email, and ask some of the staff at your school to review it to minimise it.

If after a reasonable time you don't get a response, you could try to find a student's association at the university related to your research. They could probably be able to judge it, and take it to the professor in person with their "seal of approval", that is more likely to get his attention.